# Scapy packet manipulation in standard socket

Tags: python, sockets, proxy, scapy, packet-capture

Im writing HTTP Proxy Server that will open socket with the browser and the request from the browser will go to my HTTP Proxy Server and my server will open socket with the server that the browser ask for and send him the request.
It will go like this:

**Browser** --request--> **HTTP Proxy Server** --request--> **Web Server**

**Browser** <--response-- **HTTP Proxy Server** <--response-- **Web Server**

Now I need those sockets will be clearly that I can use scapy to see the layers of each packet and manipulate it like I want to. (for security reasons e.g Block Phishing or something like that)

In this code I write simple socket with the browser just for testing and learning about browser behavior with HTTP Requests.

```
from scapy.all import *
import socket

socket_with_browser = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_STREAM)
print "Start"
socket_with_browser.bind(('127.0.0.1',8080))
socket_with_browser.listen(1)
conn , addr = socket_with_browser.accept()
stream_sock_browser = StreamSocket(conn)
r = stream_sock_browser.recv(4096)
r[TCP].show()
socket_with_browser.close()
```

I get the following Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 254, in run_nodebug
  File "C:\Python26\ProxyServer\module1.py", line 22, in <module>
    r[TCP].show()
  File "C:\Python26\Lib\site-packages\scapy\packet.py", line 817, in __getitem__
    raise IndexError("Layer [%s] not found" % lname)
IndexError: Layer [TCP] not found
```

There is a way that I can get packet from socket and use it (get packet layers or something) with scapy? Maybe I declare the socket badly? By the way Im using Windows 7 and python 2.6

Answer (score 0):

Six years late but your question might appear to others with similar issues.

The problem with your approach is that not every packet received has a TCP layer, so you should use the haslayer() method.

```py
if r.haslayer(TCP): # yes, without quotation marks
    r.show()
```